# Powershell Script to remove expired certificates

Tags: powershell, certificate

I want to create a powershell script that will remove expired certificates but I keep receiving an error.

I also changed the notafter property to display as expiration date.

```
        $today = Get-Date
        dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My\|
        select  thumbprint, subject, @{Name="ExpirationDate";Expression= 
        {$_.NotAfter}}|
        Where-Object ExpirationDate -lt $today|
        Remove-Item
```

```
Remove-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{Thumbprint=XXXX; 
Subject=CN=xyz.org, OU=X, O=X, L=X, S=X, 
C=US; NotAfter=X' does not exist.
At C:\Users\Documents\Delete Expired Certs Script.ps1:10 char:2
+  Remove-Item 
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (@{Thumbprint=70...r=:String) [Remove-Item], DriveNotFoun 
   dException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Comment: You have PowerShell 2.0 I am guessing. You need at least 3.0 for that to work.

Comment: Omit/remove the `select` part. The pipeline should be as follows: `dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My\| Where-Object NotAfter -lt $today | Remove-Item`

Comment: @Matt I'm pretty certain the cert drive exists on ps v2 as well.  The problem is they're trying to use `Remove-Item` against a `pscustomobject` they crafted with `Select-Object`.  Their syntax with `Where-Object` suggests they're on PSv3+.  Voting to close the question as off-topic: syntax error.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Its not the drive.. Its an issue with `Remove-Item` and that provider that exists in 2.0. However... I didn't notice that the object was changed in the pipeline either so likely that is the first culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function to perform this task.

Parameter options are `-CertificateStore LocalMachine` or `-CertificateStore CurrentUser`

Optional `-WhatIf` parameter will state which certificates will be removed.

Optional `-Verbose` parameter will state the certificate DN and its expiry date.

```
function Remove-ExpiredCertificates {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateSet('LocalMachine','CurrentUser')]
        [string]$CertificateStore
    )
    process{
        $today = Get-Date
        $path = "Cert:\$CertificateStore\My"
        $expiredCertList = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Where-Object -Property NotAfter -lt $today

        foreach ($certificate in $expiredCertList){
            if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("certificate $($certificate.Subject) that expired $($certificate.NotAfter)",'Remove')){
                Remove-Item -Path $certificate.PSPath -Force
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example Output:

```
PS > Remove-ExpiredCertificates -CertificateStore LocalMachine -WhatIf
What if: Performing the operation "Remove" on target "certificate CN=myoldcert.domain.local that expired 01/31/2018 11:59:00"

PS > Remove-ExpiredCertificates -CertificateStore LocalMachine
```