# Powershell Script to Remove all Expired Certificates on a Group of Servers

Tags: powershell, certificate, ssl-certificate

We are cleaning up our server environment and need to find all expired certs and delete them. The environment consists of Windows 2008 R2, Windows 2012, Windows 2012 R2 servers

I have tried several published scripts that don't work, they just say completed with no output. I tried one published in stackoverflow: [Powershell Script to remove expired certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54446586/powershell-script-to-remove-expired-certificates). I have also tried a few of the scripts below as well with no luck. Using the one by thumbprint is ok but I need to get rid of all expired certs

'''

## Delete by thumbprint

Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\D20159B7772E33A6A33E436C938C6FE764367396 | Remove-Item

## Delete by subject/serialnumber/issuer/whatever

Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My |
Where-Object { $_.Subject -match 'Frode F' } |
Remove-Item
'''
'''
$today = Get-Date
Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My |
Where-Object NotAfter -lt $today |
Remove-Item

## or

Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My |
ForEach-Object -begin { $now = get-date } -process { if ($PSItem.NotAfter -lt $now ) { $PSItem } } |
Remove-Item
'''

What I'm trying to achieve is removing ALL expired certificates on all servers in a list leveraging a foreach statement that references a list of servers in a text file, then goes out and removes all certificates expired from yesterdays date and older

Anything you guys can think of would be of great help to me

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you are trying to remove local certs or certs issued via ADCS?

You say you've tried many samples, but have you tried these:

[Remove Local Windows Certificate Store Expired Certificates](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Remove-Local-Windows-57098b6c)

> With this script you will be able to run, detect and also remove all
>   expired certificates on the affected local machine. All Certificate
>   Stores (User, Service and Computer) are checked and based on the date
>   (when run) to detect any expired certificates up to the date of
>   run.Thus t
>
> Download : Remove_local_expired_v2.ps1

[Script to query/delete (expired) certificates from a AD-CS (CA /PKI) database](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Script-to-delete-expired-8fcfcf48)

> This Cleanup-MSPKI_Cert.ps1 PowerShell Script contains 3 functions for
>   your CA (Certification Authority) AD-CS
>   (ActiveDirectory-CertificationAuthority) maintenance. You can filter
>   for certificates issued by a certain template and also delete them if
>   expired!
>
> Download : Cleanup_MSPKI_Cert_v1.2.ps1

Or use the full PKI modules from the MS powershellgallery.com

```
'*pki*','*certificate*' | 
ForEach {Find-Module -Name $PSItem } | 
Format-Table -AutoSize

# Results

Version Name                               Repository Description
------- ----                               ---------- ----------- 
1.6     PKITools                           PSGallery  Get certificates and Templates ...
3.4.1.0 PSPKI                              PSGallery  This module contains public key ...
0.0.5   CustomPKI                          PSGallery  Extended PKI CmdLets                                                                                 
3.2.0.0 xCertificate                       PSGallery  This module includes DSC resources ...
4.5.0.0 CertificateDsc                     PSGallery  This module includes DSC resources ...
0.0.4   SelfSignedCertificate              PSGallery  WARNING: This module is ...
1.0     cEprsCertificate                   PSGallery  This module instals certificates, ...
1.0.0.1 azureVpnP2SSelfSignedCertificate   PSGallery  A PowerShell module to help generate ...
1.4     CertificateHealth                  PSGallery  Certificate Health Check Module                                                                      
1.5     CertificatePS                      PSGallery  A module to enhance certificate ...
0.2.0   ExportBase64Certificate            PSGallery  Export certificates from the local ...
1.0     ACMEDNS01Certificate               PSGallery  Generate SSL Certificates using ...                                                   
0.2     Get-ADUserCertificate              PSGallery  simple module to get single or ....
2.1.0   RDPCertificate                     PSGallery  A module for generating and apply....
1.0.0.2 PowerShell.X509Certificate.Utility PSGallery  A PowerShell X509Certificate Utili...          
1.2.5   Get-WebCertificate                 PSGallery  This script makes an HTTPS web ...
1.0     xCertificatePrivateKeyAccess       PSGallery  This resource helps you manage cer...
```

Comment: I have tried the ps1 script you referenced, when I try it, it immediately says complete, yet all expired certs remain. I tried it on several servers, made sure to run as an administrator as well

Comment: Are you actually getting any cert back? Add -Verbose and -force to the Remove. You may want to consider using the Trace-Command cmdlet to get even more details. See details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/trace-command?view=powershell-6

Comment: $today = Get-Date
$ConfirmPreference = "None"
$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.x509Certificates.x509Store("My","LocalMachine")
$store.Open("ReadWrite")
$certs = $store.Certificates | Where-Object {$_.NotAfter -lt $today}
ForEach ($cert in $certs)
{
  $store.Remove($cert)
}
$store.Close()

Comment: I have 2 questions, I am noticing the $store.Open("readwrite") should this be modify or something does readwrite allow for deletion? Also could you help me with where I should place the -force option?

Comment: NTFS permissions: --- Read Permissions: Users have reading permissions of the file or folder, such as Full Control, Read, and Write. --- 
Write Attributes: Users can changet he attributes of a file or folder, such as read-only or hidden. (NTFSdefines these attributes.)  --- Delete: Users can delete the file or folder. (If users don't have the Delete permission on a file or folder, they can still delete it if they have the Delete Subfolders And Files permission on the parent folder.)

Comment: Remove-Item -Verbose -Force, but do this on a test machine first.